# EF Core cannot map a converted Enumerable property while also ignoring it as a navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have an EF-tracked entity that contains two collections. One is a navigation property while the other is not. The property which is not a navigation property has string.Join conversion as I must store a list of enumeration values without normalizing by making a table representing the enumeration.

Unfortunately, EF insists on seeing the enumeration value collection as a navigation property. The NotMapped attribute and the Ignore fluent API method are both inapplicable because the property does have to be mapped.

In the current circumstances, attempting to create a migration results in the following error.

`Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Tab.AssetTypes' of type 'List<AssetType>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

How would one allow the property to be mapped per the configured conversion while also telling EF that it is *not* a navigation property?

```cs
// Entity
public abstract partial class Tab
{
    public List<AssetTag> AssetTags { get; set; }
    public List<AssetType> AssetTypes { get; set; } // Enumeration value collection in question
}

// Fluent API config
protected override void OnModelCreatingTab<TTab>(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RocEntity<TTab>(SchemaName).Has(e =>
    {
        e
            .HasMany(t => t.AssetTags)
            .WithMany(at => at.Tabs as IEnumerable<TTab>);

        // Conversion to delimited string
        e.Property(at => at.AssetTypes)
            .HasConversion(
                t => string.Join(',', t.Select(at => at.ToString())),
                t => t
                    .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(tm => (AssetType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AssetType), tm))
                    .ToList()
            );
    });
}
```

The only reasonable solution that I can think of is to create a second property representing the delimited form of the enumeration value collection and then ignore the typed property. I really dislike making a second, unnecessary property simply to account for the vagaries of the EF monster, however.

```cs
// Naïve solution
public abstract partial class Tab
{
    public List<AssetTag> AssetTags { get; set; }

    public string AssetTypesDelimited => string.Join(',', AssetTypes.Select(at => at.ToString()));

    [NotMapped]
    public List<AssetType> AssetTypes { get; set; } // Enumeration value collection in question
}
```

Comment: Does `e.Ignore("AssetTypes");` definitely not work? And have you considered normalizing it out into a separate table, as it should be?

Comment: That would ignore the property completely, causing it to not be mapped in the DB at all. The fully normalized route would mean that I would have a DB table representing the enumeration, which, while kind of nifty, is outside the scope of this particular task and an unnecessary addition to the DB - two new tables. I'd prefer my naive solution to that option, honestly.

Comment: It would be good if you provide realistic example reproducing your issue. Normally this setup works. But you seem to be using some sort of a inheritance strategy, custom generic `OnModelCreatingTab<TTab>(ModelBuilder builder)` method which is unknown if called for all entities included in the model. And the error is reporting the problem for the base abstract entity (?) `Tab.AssetTypes`  so the inheritance strategy also could play.  Or another navigation property bringing `Tab` to the model (this cast is suspicious `.WithMany(at => at.Tabs as IEnumerable<TTab>)`. Shortly, we need [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the column type to the configuration which *might* override  the expectation to treat it as a navigation property, but I'd say it's a long shot:

```
    e.Property(at => at.AssetTypes)
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)")
        .HasConversion(
            t => string.Join(',', t.Select(at => at.ToString())),
            t => t
                .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(tm => (AssetType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AssetType), tm))
                .ToList()
        );
```

Your work around should work, especially when creating and persisting new Tags, though not sure if that will work when editing existing entities, getting the delimited string back into the collection. You would need to alias the delimited string using `[Column("AssetTypes")]` or the `HasColumnName()` Fluent method, and you cannot use the Asset Types collection in Linq2SQL expressions, which I fully suspect would also be a limitation when using `.HasConversion()`.

When dealing with client-side transformations like these I tend to want to keep the entities reflecting the data state and either leave the transformation as a ViewModel responsibility, or if it makes sense to transform at the entity level I will opt for a similar approach but following a more DDD means of guarding the collection. When dealing with collection navigation properties you typically want to allow items to be added and removed, but guard the collection  Setter to deter things like setting a new collection. With something that will translate into a delimited string you would want to capture when items are added and removed to both update the collection but ensure the delimited string reflects this as well. The delimited string does not need to be exposed as a property by using a backing field:

```
private string _assetTypesDelimited = string.Empty;

private List<AssetType>? _assetTypes = null; 
[NotMapped]
public IReadOnlyCollection<AssetType> AssetTypes
{
    get => _assetTypes ??= _assetTypesDelimited.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(tm => (AssetType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AssetType), tm)
        .ToList();
};

public void AddAssetType(AssetType assetType)
{
    if(AssetTypes.Contains(assetType)) return;

    _assetTypes.Add(assetType);
    _assetTypesDelimited = string.Join(',', _assetTypes.Select(at => at.ToString()));
}

public void RemoveAssetType(AssetType assetType)
{
    if(!AssetTypes.Contains(assetType)) return;

    _assetTypes.Remove(assetType);
    _assetTypesDelimited = string.Join(',', _assetTypes.Select(at => at.ToString()));
}
```

Then with the entity configuration we register the backing field:

```
.Property("_assetTypesDelimited") // Registers the backing field with EF
    .HasColumnName("AssetTypes");
```

In this way the delimited string is not exposed, while the collection is relatively guarded with actions to add and remove entries (optionally a `ClearAssetTypes()` could be added as well) ensuring the backing field is updated as values are added and removed.

Please note this code is just pulled out of my head so it may need some tweaking to work properly, but should hopefully provide some ideas to try. Ideally it would be better if the schema was normalized with a simple many-to-many relationship between Tabs and AssetTypes rather than delimited lists, but sometimes we're stuck with what is already there.